# How to reset RaspberryPi network configuration to default

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, static-ip

I've been cloning RPI images for several months and kept adding stuff without keeping track of the changes made to the .conf files. I've messed with the network settings to a point where remote (=teamviewer) access seems to run unstable, which is bad for my application.

I've checked previous topics on this:
[Link1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121567/how-to-reset-all-network-settings-raspian-buster)
[Link2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54061/network-configuration-reset-bridge-wlan1-to-eth0)
[Link3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57393/how-to-reset-the-wifi-configuration-in-raspbian)
[Link4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72251/how-to-reset-wlan-configuration-on-boot-on-a-raspberry-pi-3)

But I couldn't really find a 'best practice' for bringing the network settings to the default state again. I'm in particular interested in the wlan0 settings.

Thank you!

Comment: The "default" would be something that only works for ethernet.  You need some kind of "non-default" configuration to conntect to encrypted wifi.  There's also a strongly implied [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) here.  That said, I'm sure there's a way to get `apt` to re-install configuration files for specific packages, which would be a default state (although it may not be exactly the same as when those packages were first installed, if updated versions included config tweaks etc).

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124446/raspberrypi-cannot-be-accessed-by-teamviewer-from-external-network